# Could any one help me how to stop and start azure webjobs through vsts?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have found one plugin azure app service webjob start in VSTS but I can't start/stop the webjob.Please help me guys. I am getting the below error while running the task in VSTS.

**Error:**

```
2017-09-25T12:26:37.3203696Z Preparing task execution handler.
2017-09-25T12:26:43.2660796Z Executing the powershell script: 
 d:\a\_tasks\Start_cbebb02b-11c6-4e24-b5a8-0b51366d51b7\0.2.5\Start.ps1
2017-09-25T12:26:43.6830868Z ##
[error]System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException: At 
D:\a\_tasks\Start_cbebb02b-11c6-4e24-b5a8-0b51366d51b7\0.2.5\Start.ps1:13 
char:16
2017-09-25T12:26:43.6830868Z +     $WebAppName
2017-09-25T12:26:43.6830868Z +                ~
2017-09-25T12:26:43.6830868Z Missing ')' in function parameter list.
2017-09-25T12:26:43.6830868Z 
2017-09-25T12:26:43.6830868Z At D:\a\_tasks\Start_cbebb02b-11c6-4e24-b5a8-
0b51366d51b7\0.2.5\Start.ps1:17 char:1
2017-09-25T12:26:43.6830868Z + )
2017-09-25T12:26:43.6830868Z + ~
2017-09-25T12:26:43.6830868Z Unexpected token ')' in expression or 
statement.
```

Comment: First, the ResourceGroupName is incorrect ('/' is invalid), check it in your azure portal. Secondly, The ResourceType is incorrect, it should be Microsoft.Web/sites/TriggeredWebJob or Microsoft.Web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs. On the other hand, is name of your web job called webjobname?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help starain-MSFT. It worked well now.Really appreciating.

Comment: Hi MSFT, I have 10 continuous and 10 triggered webjobs so how can I build the code.Currently I am running the script which you provided. 
 Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName XXX -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/TriggeredWebJobs -ResourceName [web app name]/[web job name] -Action run -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -force....So I want to stop/start multiple webjobs and my azure power shell task is not supporting more than 5 lines to run this command individually for each webjob.So please help me out.

Comment: You can pass them through the parameter and iterate the array, check the update of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Invoke-AzureRMResourceAction` command:

1. Add Azure PowerShell task to build/release definition

Code:

Triggered WebJob:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName XXX -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/TriggeredWebJobs -ResourceName [web app name]/[web job name] -Action run -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -force
```

Continuous WebJob:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName XXX -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ResourceName [web app name]/[web job name] -Action [start/stop] -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

Simple sample script with multiple webjobs:

```
param(
    [object[]]$webjobs,
    [string]$website,
    [string]$rg
)
foreach($wj in $webjobs){
 if($wj.typeName -eq "continuous")
 {
 Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $rg -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ResourceName "$website/$($wj.name)" -Action start -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
 }
 else{
  Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $rg -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/TriggeredWebJobs -ResourceName "$website/$($wj.name)" -Action run -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -force
 }
}
```

Specify parameter:

```
-webjobs @(@{"name"="webjob1";"typeName"='continuous'},@{"name"="webjob2";"typeName"='continuous'},@{"name"="webjob3";"typeName"='triggered '}) -website XX -rg XX
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where and how can I include this step as I am running only this below command :                                                            Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName XXX -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ResourceName [web app name]/[web job name] -Action [start/stop] -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force...so how can I relate the above script which you have given now.I have azure powershell plugin in that I can see 2 steps :1.inline script 2.Script arguments.So,Please help me out pal because I am new to powershell script.So asking doubts.

Comment: Is it possible to share your mail ID or contact so that I can reach out to you please ? Please help me out pal,how can I include the above script which you have given and with that script how can I stop all the web jobs.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN Which point you do not clear? I update the script. If the PowerShell script is too long, you can try to remove the whitespace or you can use File Path type and specify the PowerShell script file.

Comment: Really appreciating you..It worked now..Great man..Thanks a lot for helping me in these things..

Comment: Hi MSFT, I got requirement from team like ,currently they are running the triggered jobs at particular intervals by setting up the schedule.They have setup schedule ,so as per the scheduled time those triggered jobs will run but at the time of deploy we must make sure the triggered jobs shouldn't run as it will not accept the deploy jar's into azure.So I want to run webjobs continuous jobs stop and as well as triggered jobs shouldn't run.It should check the triggered job running at the time of deploy if its running we can't deploy jar's even though if u stop continuous jobs.Please help me.

Comment: How to accomplish the above task? whether we need to add any script to check triggered jobs running or not if it runs how to deploy jar's.

Comment: And other requirement is like,currently we are passing the parameters like   -webjobs @(@{"name"="abc";"typeName"='continuous'},@{"name"="def";"typeName"='continuous'}) -website kgh -rg ghi....But team want these parameters will be passed in a separate file.So that when they add new web job they can add in a file itself.how can I call if I put the parameter script in a separate file and pass to the webjobs script.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN I'd suggest asking separate questions in new forum threads.

Comment: I have opened separate forum for this request. Please help me pal.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static string token = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"];
        public static string continuouswebjobs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["continuouswebjobs"];
        public static string triggeredwebjobs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["triggeredwebjobs"];
        public static string hostName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DLUHostName"];

        public static void StopContinuousWebJob(TextWriter log)
        {
            HttpClient request = new HttpClient();
            request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
            request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuouswebjobs))
            {
                string[] jobsArray = continuouswebjobs.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < jobsArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = request.PostAsync(new Uri(hostName + "continuouswebjobs/" + jobsArray[i] + "/stop"), null).Result;
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Job " + jobsArray[i] + " stopped  successfully.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, format your code as code (this would be virtually impossible to follow) and include a bit more of explanation along.