# How to stop currently running WebJobs on Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobs

I am trying to deploy a new version of WebJobs. I have `webjobs.yml` file like;

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

if I try to stop like below, I am receiving error;

```
- task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'connectedServiceNameARM'
    azureServiceConnection: '$(apiName)'
    method: 'DELETE'
    urlSuffix: 'https://$(apiName).scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/$(apiName)-webjobs'
    waitForCompletion: 'true'
```

[WebJobs-API documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#delete-a-triggered-job)

[Step references task InvokeRESTAPI at version 1.152.1 which is not valid for the given job target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57294014/step-references-task-invokerestapi-at-version-1-152-1-which-is-not-valid-for-the)

And if I use `pool: server`, as suggested I cannot execute other tasks.

also I tried to use STOP/START like below. It stops AppService but not WebJobs.

```
- task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(apiName)'
    Action: 'Stop Azure App Service'
    WebAppName: '$(apiName)'
```

And I am eventually getting error from Azure:

```
The process cannot access the file XYZ because it is being used by another process.
```

So, how I can **stop currently running WebJobs from Azure Pipelines**, and deploy new version?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions here, you can refer to:

The first is you can set this sticky app setting on the staging slot:

- WEBJOBS_STOPPED: 1

Set this setting to 1 to disable running any job (will also stop all currently running jobs) Source : [Kudu Wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#configuration-settings),[case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719134/how-to-stop-continuous-and-remove-schedule-from-schedules-web-jobs-in-vsts)

The second is you can use `Invoke-AzureRMResourceAction` command. Adding `Azure PowerShell` task to definition. Source: [case1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405285/could-any-one-help-me-how-to-stop-and-start-azure-webjobs-through-vsts) [case2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027845/what-is-the-best-way-to-stop-triggered-web-jobs).

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName XXX -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ResourceName [web app name]/[web job name] -Action [start/stop] -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I used inline script in Azure Cli task to update appsettings:

To stop all:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --name MyAppServiceName --resource-group MyAppServiceResourceGroup --subscription MyAppServiceSubscription --settings WEBJOBS_DISABLE_SCHEDULE=1 WEBJOBS_STOPPED=1
```